# Javascript : Change img src After some interval of time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Guys I don't know how to add some interval of time in javascript. Do you know how to add some time before changing src of an image. i get this code from [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_dom_image)

```js
document.getElementById("image").src = "http://www.w3schools.com/js/landscape.jpg";
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<img id="image" src="http://www.w3schools.com/js/smiley.gif" width="160" height="120">

<p>The original image was smiley.gif, but the script changed it to landscape.jpg</p>

</body>
</html>
```

[**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/0or96njh/1/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
setTimeout(function() {
                      document.getElementById("image").setAttribute("src", "http://www.w3schools.com/js/landscape.jpg");
                  }, 5000);
```

```html
<img id="image" src="http://www.w3schools.com/js/smiley.gif" width="160" height="120">

<p>The original image was smiley.gif, but the script changed it to landscape.jpg</p>
```

I have updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0or96njh/2/)